# Why my code is not counting first word of my String

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to put words with their length in an array. But it is not counting my first word.
Here is my code:

```
public class wordLength {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s="please come in";
        String collection="";
        String [] wordslength=new String[10];
        for(int k=0;k<s.length();k++){
            char c=s.charAt(k);
            if(c==' '){
                wordslength[collection.length()]=collection;
                collection="";
            }
            collection =collection+c;
        }
        for(int k=1;k<10;k++){
            System.out.println("at index "+ (k-1) +"result is "+wordslength[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int k=1;k<10;k++)` arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: Your loop runs only 9 times (1 to 9 inclusive)!

Answer (score 2):

change

```
for(int k=1;k<10;k++)
{
    System.out.println("at index "+ (k-1) +"result is "+wordslength[k]);
}

to 

for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
{
    System.out.println("at index "+ k +"result is "+wordslength[k]);
}
```

for your problem exactly...

```
public class wordLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "please come in";
        String[] wordslength = new String[10];
        String[] allStrings = s.split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < allStrings.length; k++) {
            wordslength[allStrings[k].length()] = allStrings[k];

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            System.out.println("at index " + (k) + "result is " + wordslength[k]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `"at index "+ (k-1) +"result is` gives `-1` then Oo

Comment: change `k-1` to `k` in the print too

Comment: I changed it but nothing changed but only index changed.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing starts at 0, you have taken it from 1. Please access the 0th index. Change it as.

```
 for(int k=1;k<10;k++){
            System.out.println("at index "+ (k-1) +"result is "+wordslength[k-1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
public class WordLength {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "please come in";
    String collection = "";
    String[] wordslength = new String[10];
    for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
        char c = s.charAt(k);
        if (c == ' ') {
            wordslength[collection.length()] = collection;
            collection = "";

        }
        collection = collection + c;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        System.out.println("at index " + (k) + " result is " + wordslength[k]);
    }
}
```

}

Also keep in mind that is good the { to be on the previous line of the body you are creating. Classes are with uppercase letter. These two are just better convention in java world for better code reading in future. There are many style rules available in internet for almost all IDEs for the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must be more accurate in your code, I think your should use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class wordLength {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s="please come in";
        String collection="";
        ArrayList<String> wordslength=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int k=0;k<s.length();k++)
        {
            char c=s.charAt(k);
            if(c==' ')
            {
                wordslength.add( collection );
                collection="";

            }
            collection = collection + c;
        }

        if( collection != " ")
        {
            wordslength.add( collection );
            collection="";

        }

        for( int k = 0 ; k < wordslength.size() ; k++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "at index " + (k) + " result is " + wordslength.get(k) + " with length " +wordslength.get(k).length() );
        }
    }

}
```

[try it here](http://tpcg.io/Ouhbnb)

Aslo, take attention to code indentation and class nomenclature